# List USB Human Interface Devices (HIDs) in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, usb, hid, gamepad

I'm trying to work with gamepads, so I'd like to start by listing all the HIDs connected to my machine.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW2) has code samples which no longer work, so I thought I'd recreate it.

Following that documentation, I've attempted to create an IOHIDManager, but it does not autocomplete in and I get the error "Use of Unresolved Identifier".

```
import IOKit
//...
let x = IOHIDManager // does not exist
```

Is it possible to list HIDs using Swift, or must I write these portions in Obj-C?

Comment: Add `import IOKit.hid` (found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6077)

Comment: Adding `IOKit.hid` won't work. As said on the link you provided, it says "You can get the headers/declarations into a Swift playground using
(...) But it will just result in a runtime error". You will have to use Objective-C to achieve your goal.